# Read .html file as a string without TAGS

Tags: android, html, parsing

My target is to parse the content of html into a string, but I need the raw content without the TAGs (I need the text which is displayed in the web view) and not the whole thing for now I have the following

```
                try
                {

                    InputStream is = null;
                    is = getContext().getAssets().open("test.html");

                    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder("");

                    int read;
                    char[] buff = new char[1024];
                    while ((read = r.read(buff)) != -1)
                    {
                        details.append(buff, 0, read);
                    }

                     // Till here i managed to get the content but still have
                    // the problem of TAGs and the output is like this


                    /*<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
                     <!-- saved from url=(0051)http://77.235.135.51:8081//HTMLFiles/file22782.html -->
                     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
                     <script src="./test_files/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js.download" type="text/javascript"></script>
                     <link href="./test_files/Mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                     <script src="./test_files/HighlightSearch.js.download" type="text/javascript"></script>
                     </head><body><div class="Section0"><p style="text-align:left;page-break-inside:auto;page-break-after:auto;page-break-before:auto;line-height:13.8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:10pt;"></p>
                     <p class="قانون">تعميم رقم 2 لسنة 2010</p>

                     <p class="عنوان-للقانون"><a id="_Toc463352331">بشأن جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز الدورة الثالثة 2010/2011</a></p>
                     <p class="فقرة">إلى كافة الدوائر والجهات الحكومية في الإمارة</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">استنادا لقرار رئيس المجلس التنفيذي  رقم (59) لسنة 2008 بشأن استحداث إدارة جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز بالأمانة للمجلس التنفيذي، فقد تبنت جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز في مضمون رسالتها أن تعمل على توفير العوامل والأساليب اللازمة لرفع مستوى الأداء التَّنظيميِّ لكافَّة الجهات الحكوميّة في إمارة أبوظبي، وذلك من خلال تبنِّي مبادئ الجودة الشّاملة والتَّميز التي تؤدّي بدورها إلى رفع كفاءة العاملين وتحسين العمليِّات التشغيلِيّة وتبسيط الإجراءات ممّا يحقق أفضل نتائج الأداء.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">وبناءً على ذلك، تم إدخال إجراءات جديدة مستحدثة سيتم الإعلان عنها خلال الدورات التعريفية لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز وذلك لإثراء عملية التقييم وإعطاء قيمة مضافة أكبر.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">يرجى من الجهات المشاركة الالتزام بالشروط والضوابط المقررة في هذا الشأن وتسهيل مهمة عمل مكتب جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز في تأدية عمله لتحقيق الأهداف المرجوة.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">لإجراءاتكم</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">وفقكم الله،،،</p>
                     <p class="فقرة صدر">التاريخ: 27/5/2010 م.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة الامضاء">محـــمد أحمــد البـــواردي</p>
                     <p class="فقرة الامضاء">الأمين العام– رئيس الجائزة</p>
                     <p class="نشر">نشر هذا التعميم في عدد الجريدة الرسمية رقم 5 تاريخ 31 مايو 2010م. ص 22.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">المرفقات:</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">- مرفق 1: الشروط الواجب توافرها لأهلية مشاركة الجهات والمؤسسات في جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز مع قائمة الجهات والمؤسسات المؤهلة  للمشاركة في الدورة الثالثة لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">- مرفق 2: قائمة الجهات والمؤسسات المستثناة من المشاركة في الدورة الثالثة 2010/2011 لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز والتي شاركت في الدورة الثانية  2008/2009.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">- مرفق 3: قائمة جوائز الدورة الثالثة 2010/2011 لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">- مرفق 4: المواعيد الرئيسية للدورة الثالثة 2010/2011 لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">- مرفق 5: منع استخدام الاستشاريين الخارجيين بأعمال مرتبطة بجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز.</p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352332">مرفق 1</a></p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352333">الشروط الواجب توافرها لأهلية مشاركة الجهات والمؤسسات في جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز مع قائمة الجهات والمؤسسات المؤهلة  للمشاركة في الدورة الثالثة لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز</a></p>
                     <p class="فقرة">البند الأول: الشروط الواجب توافرها لأهلية مشاركة الجهات والمؤسسات في جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">الجهات الحكومية:</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">1- أن تكون جهة حكومية تتبع حكومة أبوظبي </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">2- أن تكون دائرة حكومية أو هيئة عامة أو ما في حكمها</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">3- أن تكون جهة خدمية وليست للربحية </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">4- لها وجود فعلي في وقت اعتماد أسماء المؤسسات المشاركة للدورة</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">ملاحظة: يجب على الجهات الحكومية والتي يمكن أن تشارك بشكل اختياري إرسال خطاب رسمي بطلب المشاركة بذلك</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">المؤسسات الحكومية التابعة ( SOEs): </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">1- أن تكون مؤسسة حكومية تتبع حكومة أبوظبي </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">2- تكون مؤسسة حكومية تابعة على مستوى شركة قابضة</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">3- مملوكة 100% للحكومة </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">4- لها وجود فعلي في وقت اعتماد أسماء المؤسسات المشاركة للدورة </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">5- مؤسسة تقدم خدمات عامة للجمهور (Public Service Provider)</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">ملاحظة: المؤسسات العامة والتي ينطبق عليها الشروط الأربعة الأولى يمكن أن تشارك بشكل اختياري ويجب عليها إرسال خطاب رسمي بذلك</p>
                     <div><div align="center"><img class="jadwalImg" id="toggleText1001" alt="" rel="#displayText1001" src="./test_files/tbl_icon.png"></div><div class="simple_overlay" id="displayText1001"><a class="close"></a><div align="center" class="PopupTableView"><table cellspacing="0" style=" border-collapse: collapse; width: 518pt; "><tbody><tr style="height: 2px"><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:98.86667px;"><p class="فقرة">التصنيف</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:274.3333px;"><p class="فقرة">الجهات الحكومية</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:318px;"><p class="فقرة">المؤسسات الحكومية التابعة ( SOEs)</p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height: 2px"><td style="vertical-align:top;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:98.86667px;"><p class="فقرة">مشاركة إلزامية</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:top;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:274.3333px;"><p class="فقرة">1- المركز الوطني للتأهيل</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">2- الادارة العامة للإقامة وشؤون الأجانب – أبوظبي</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">3- المؤسسة العليا للمناطق الاقتصادية المتخصصة </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">4- القياده العامه لشرطة ابوظبي </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">5- جهاز ابوظبي للرقابه الغذائية </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">6-  جهاز حماية المنشآت والمرافق الحيويه </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">7- شركة أبوظبي للخدمات العامة (مساندة)</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">8- صندوق خليفة لتطوير المشاريع </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">9- صندوق معاشات ومكافآت التقاعد لامارة ابوظبي </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">10- طيران الرئاسة</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">11- دائرة الشؤون البلدية </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">12- دائرة الشؤون البلدية - بلدية ابوظبي </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">13- دائرة الشؤون البلدية - بلدية المنطقه الغربيه </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">14- دائرة الشؤون البلدية - بلدية العين </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">15- دائرة المالية</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">16- دائرة التنمية الاقتصادية</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">17- دائرة النقل </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">18- دائرة القضاء – أبوظبي</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">19- دار زايد للثقافه الاسلامية </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">20- مؤسسة التنمية الاسرية</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">21- مؤسسة زايد العليا للرعاية الإنسانية وذوي الاحتياجات الخاصة </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">22- مجلس ابوظبي للتعليم </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">23- مجلس ابوظبي للتخطيط العمراني </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">24- مجلس ابوظبي للتوطين </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">25- مجلس أبوظبي للتطوير الاقتصادي </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">26- مجلس تنمية المنطقة الغربيه </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">27- مجلس ابوظبي الرياضي </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">28- مركز أبوظبي للأنظمة الإلكترونية والمعلومات </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">29- مركز الإحصاء </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">30- مركز تنظيم النقل لسيارات الأجرة </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">31- مركز ادارة النفايات </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">32- مكتب التنظيم والرقابة لقطاع الماء والكهرباء</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">33- هيئة البيئة </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">34- هيئة السياحة </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">35- هيئة الصحة</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">36- هيئة المنطقة الإعلامية -أبوظبي</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">37- هيئة ابوظبي للثقافة والتراث</p>
                     <p class="فقرة"></p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:top;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:318px;"><p class="فقرة">1- شركة أبوظبي للخدمات الصحية (صحة) </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">2- شركة الصرف الصحي</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">3- هيئة مياه وكهرباء أبوظبي</p>
                     <p class="فقرة"></p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height: 2px"><td style="vertical-align:top;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:98.86667px;"><p class="فقرة">مشاركة اختيارية</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:top;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:274.3333px;"><p class="فقرة">1- المؤسسة العامة لحديقة الحيوان والأحياء المائية بالعين</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">2- مؤسسة الرعاية الإجتماعية وشؤون القصر</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:top;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:318px;"><p class="فقرة">1- سوق أبوظبي للأوراق المالية </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">2- شركة أبوظبي للإعلام</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">3- شركة المعارض</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">4- شركة الإتحاد للطيران</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">5- شركة مطارات أبوظبي</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">6- شركة أبوظبي للموانئ </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">7- صندوق أبوظبي للتنمية </p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height:0px;"><td style="width:74.15px;"></td><td style="width:205.75px;"></td><td style="width:238.5px;"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="clear: both"></div></div></div><p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352334">مرفق 2</a></p>
                     <p class="فقرة">قائمة الجهات والمؤسسات المستثناة من المشاركة في الدورة الثالثة 2010/2011 لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز والتي شاركت في الدورة الثانية 2008/2009</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">1- الأمانة العامة للمجلس الإستشاري الوطني </p>
                     <p class="فقرة">2- غرفة تجارة وصناعة أبوظبي</p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352335">مرفق 3</a></p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352336">قائمة جوائز الدورة الثالثة 2010/2011 لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز</a></p>
                     <p style="text-align:center;page-break-inside:auto;page-break-after:auto;page-break-before:auto;line-height:13.8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:10pt;"></p><div align="center"><img class="jadwalImg" id="toggleImage1000" alt="" rel="#displayImage1000" src="./test_files/photo_icon.png"></div><div class="simple_overlay" id="displayImage1000"><a class="close"></a><div align="center" class="PopupImageView"><img src="./test_files/AUH-ICode-Ar_2010-05-27_00002_Taa_img1.png" width="679" height="600" alt="img1"></div><div style="clear: both"></div></div><br><p></p>
                     <p class="فقرة">تكون المشاركة إلزامية في الفئة الأولى واختيارية في الفئة الثانية والثالثة والرابعة</p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352337">مرفق 4</a></p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352338">المواعيد الرئيسية للدورة الثالثة 2010/2011</a></p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352339">لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز</a></p>
                     <div><div align="center"><img class="jadwalImg" id="toggleText1002" alt="" rel="#displayText1002" src="./test_files/tbl_icon.png"></div><div class="simple_overlay" id="displayText1002"><a class="close"></a><div align="center" class="PopupTableView"><table cellspacing="0" style=" border-collapse: collapse; "><tbody><tr style="height: 32.2px"><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">الحدث</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">التاريخ</p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height: 32.2px"><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">الدورة التعريفية لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">سبتمبر / أكتوبر 2010</p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height: 32.2px"><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">الموعد النهائي لتقديم الوثائق</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">15 ديسمبر 2010</p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height: 32.2px"><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">موعد التقييم (الزيارات الميدانية والمقابلات)</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">يناير/فبراير 2011</p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height: 32.2px"><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">اعتماد النتائج والحفل الختامي</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">مارس 2011</p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height: 32.2px"><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">توزيع تقارير التعقيب</p>
                     </td><td style="vertical-align:middle;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000;border-top-width:0.5pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#000000;border-left-width:0.5pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000;border-right-width:0.5pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom-width:0.5pt;padding-left:0pt;padding-right:0pt;padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;width:319.2px;"><p class="فقرة">أبريل 2011</p>
                     </td></tr><tr style="height:0px;"><td style="width:239.4px;"></td><td style="width:239.4px;"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="clear: both"></div></div></div><p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352340">مرفق 5</a></p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352341">منع استخدام الاستشاريين الخارجين بأعمال مرتبطة</a></p>
                     <p class="قانون الباب"><a id="_Toc463352342">بجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز</a></p>
                     <p class="فقرة">تدعم جائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز رؤية الإمارة وذلك من خلال تبني مبادئ الجودة الشاملة والتميز.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">ومن ذلك، ووفقاً لما تقتضيه المصلحة العامة، يمنع استخدام الاستشاريين الخارجيين (جزئياً أو كلياً) بأي نشاط يرتبط بإعداد وثائق التقديم أو عملية التقييم لجائزة أبوظبي للأداء الحكومي المتميز. ولمكتب الجائزة الحق في التحقق من تطبيق هذا التعميم بما يروه مناسباً.</p>
                     <p class="فقرة">وفي حال ثبوت استخدام الاستشاريين، سيتم شطب مشاركة المؤسسة من الجائزة ورفع تقرير لمعالي رئيس الجائزة ويتم العمل بالتعميم من تاريخه.</p>
                     <p style="text-align: center;"><img src="./test_files/BlackFish.jpeg"></p>
                     </div></body></html>*/


                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But all i need is the value of the TAGs and not the TAGs so that i can insert the raw text into SQLite and make Full Text Search (FTS3 or FTS4) on the raw content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jsoup to parse HTML. Refer to the [Jsoup Cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/) here.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements e = doc.select(TAG);
String content = e.text();
```

Use the `text()` function to extract the text contents inside a HTML tag.

Comment: Do you have the dependency of the JSOUP library?